# How to create an animation that deforms gradually a flat circular sector to a cone?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

I want to create an animation that gradually deforms a flat circular sector to a cone. I am inspired by a question titled [How to deform a 2d shape to make a 3d object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-deform-a-2d-shape-to-make-a-3d-object).

The following source code can be used as a starting point. The lack of knowledge of differential geometry makes me have no idea what to do next.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}% Peter Lewintan
\usepackage{pst-solides3d,pst-math,multido,xfp}

\def\associate#1{\begin{pspicture}(-1.8,-2.8)(1.8,3.2)
\defFunction{associated}(u,v)
{#1 Cos v SINH mul u Sin mul #1 Sin v COSH mul u Cos mul add}
{#1 Cos v SINH mul u Cos mul neg #1 Sin v COSH mul u Sin mul add}
{#1 Cos u mul #1 Sin v mul add}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,base=pi neg pi -1
1,function=associated,ngrid=25 25,linewidth=0.001]
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\psset{Decran=15}
\multido{\ik=0+1}{72}{%
 \def\K{\fpeval{.08726646259971*\ik}}%
 \associate{\K}%
}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated with any tools you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how to do an animation. But I think I can help you with the transitions, if what you need is something like the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\def\r {1}    % radius
\def\h {2}    % height
\def\np{20}   % number of base points
\def\nt{4}    % number of transitions
\pgfmathsetmacro\s {4.5*\r}           % separation between transitions
\pgfmathsetmacro\g{sqrt(\r*\r+\h*\h)} % generatrix
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{360*\r/\g}         % sector angle
% Initial and final points
\coordinate (I0) at (0,0,0);   % initial vertex
\coordinate (F0) at (0,0,\h);  % final vertex
\foreach\i in {1,...,\np}
{%
  \coordinate (I\i) at ({\a/(\np-1)*(\i-1)-0.5*\a}:\g); % initial base point
  \coordinate (F\i) at ({360/(\np-1)*(\i-1)-180}:\r);   % final base point
}
\foreach\j in {0,...,\nt}
{% Axes
  \draw[-latex,red] (-45:\s*\j) --++ (1.25*\h,0,0) node [right] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex,red] (-45:\s*\j) --++ (0,1.25*\h,0) node [left]  {$y$};
  \draw[-latex,red] (-45:\s*\j) --++ (0,0,1.25*\h) node [above] {$z$};
  \fill[red] (-45:\s*\j) circle (1pt);
  \foreach\i in {1,...,\np}
  {% Cone
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\k{\i-1}
    \draw ($(I0)!{\j/\nt}!(F0)+(-45:\s*\j)$)   -- ($(I\i)!{\j/\nt}!(F\i)+(-45:\s*\j)$);
    \draw ($(I\i)!{\j/\nt}!(F\i)+(-45:\s*\j)$) -- ($(I\k)!{\j/\nt}!(F\k)+(-45:\s*\j)$);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, for an animation you won't need the displacements `(-45:\s*\j)` that I added to separate the transitions.

**Update:** I made the transitions in a beamer document. I think that way it's easier to see the animation steps. It's basically the same code minus the said displacements `(-45:\s*\j)` that now are not necessary. I changed the size too and added more transitions, but all that is customizable.

```
\documentclass {beamer}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\def\r {2}    % radius
\def\h {3}    % height
\def\np{20}   % number of base points
\def\nt{20}   % number of transitions
\pgfmathsetmacro\g{sqrt(\r*\r+\h*\h)} % generatrix
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{360*\r/\g}         % sector angle
% Initial and final points
\coordinate (I0) at (0,0,0);   % initial vertex
\coordinate (F0) at (0,0,\h);  % final vertex
\foreach\i in {1,...,\np}
{%
  \coordinate (I\i) at ({\a/(\np-1)*(\i-1)-0.5*\a}:\g); % initial base point
  \coordinate (F\i) at ({360/(\np-1)*(\i-1)-180}:\r);   % final base point
}
\foreach\j in {0,...,\nt}
{
  \only<\j>
  {% Axes
    \useasboundingbox (0,0,0) -- (1.25*\h,0,0) -- (0,1.25*\h,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[-latex,red] (0,0,0) --++ (1.25*\h,0,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex,red] (0,0,0) --++ (0,1.25*\h,0) node [left]  {$y$};
    \draw[-latex,red] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1.25*\h) node [above] {$z$};
    \fill[red]        (0,0,0) circle (1pt);
    \foreach\i in {1,...,\np}
    {% Cone
      \draw ($(I0)!{\j/\nt}!(F0)$)   -- ($(I\i)!{\j/\nt}!(F\i)$);
      \ifnum \i > 1
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\k{\i-1}
        \draw ($(I\i)!{\j/\nt}!(F\i)$) -- ($(I\k)!{\j/\nt}!(F\k)$);
      \fi
    }
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Update 2:** Added an `\useasboundingbox` to make the axes stationary, as the OP suggested, and remove duplicate lines with an `\ifnum`

[image]

Comment: @KimJongUn, I didn't see that, but I think it's solved now.

Comment: I think you can use `standalone` with `beamer` option. I have seen someone doing so.